# Resize get_custom_logo() inside fpdf

Tags: wordpress, fpdf

I want to show wordpress logo in PDF file using FPDF but following code showing it in larger size of logo required. How I can resize it

```
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->Cell(5,5);
 $pdf->WriteHTML(get_custom_logo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Applied following code through filter

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'wecodeart_com' );

function wecodeart_com() {
    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
            wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, array('100', '100'), false, array(
                'class'    => 'custom-logo',
            ) )
        );
    return $html;   
}
```